# how to deploy flask on centos server?

Tags: flask, deployment, centos

I have to deploy my flask app on centos server. I ran it using command python **init**.py . It started running on port 5000. I checked my server ip and tried to access it through browser on my laptop. But I am unable to access it.

Comment: Does your server have port 5000 open? Is flask running to accept incoming connections from any host (flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5000)? Did your flask process stop running when you closed the terminal on the server? These are all things to check and then update your question with more details.

Comment: yes server port 5000 is open and  flask is  running to accept incoming connections from any host. I am using app.run(host='0.0.0.0') in code. I have run this app in background. I used command: (python __init__.py &) to run python app in background. I used netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN to check whether python flask is running or not and  I can see this: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26659/python  . I also ping server from my laptop and that is also working fine.